# Javascript pop up selector

Tags: javascript

When I click java script button, i want it to pop up a mode selector alert type box,

```
|----------------------------------------------| 
|"Select Mode:"                                |
|mode A <radio button here>                    |
|mode B <radio button here>                    |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

then get the value of mode .........as A or B
How can i do this??

Comment: You want a `modal window`, of which there are ***plenty*** of implementations you can use. [See here](http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html) (searched Google for "modal window JavaScript").

Answer (score 0):

try to use the below user control from CodeProject

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/163069/Returning-a-value-from-a-modal-popup